# When does Star Wars Resistance take place?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-resistance

Star Wars Resistance is a animated series set between episodes 6 and 7, so between 5 ABY and 30 ABY, but can there be a more exact time and date? **In what year(s) do the events of Star Wars Resistance take place?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not much to go on, but at one point, there was apparently a blurb buried in the page source on starwars.com identifying it as "**about six months before The Force Awakens**":

[image: Purported screenshot of the source of starwars.com]

Text:

> Set about six months before The Force Awakens, Star Wars Resistance tells the story of Kazuda Xiono, a young pilot recruited by the Resistance and tasked with a top-secret mission to spy on the growing threat of the First Order.

(source: https://twitter.com/Darth_Hardy/status/1031053502523424768, https://old.reddit.com/r/StarWarsLeaks/comments/98ixhl/resistance_is_set_six_months_before_tfa/e4gglgf/)

Since this didn't appear visibly on the official site, this should be taken with a grain of salt, but it seems likely that it's at least officially approved (but not technically released) descriptive text.